# Jquery UI Tooltip moves out of parent div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I have a jQuery tooltip as given in the following link:

http://jsfiddle.net/ronnykroy/amYZW/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child" title="It has been a very long text">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent{
  position:absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:#00f;
}

#child{
  position:absolute;
  left:400px;
  width: 100px;
  height:150px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
.tooltipclass{
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}
```

With Jquery as follows:

```
$("#child").tooltip({
  track: true,
  tooltipClass: "tooltipclass"
});
```

Now when i hover over 'child' i don't want the tooltip to move outside parent i.e the tooltip should be confined within the 'parent' dynamically.

Comment: you can try position option,`http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`position`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position) option in jQueryUI Tooltip's API.  The `position` option uses [`jQuery UI Position`](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) so make sure look into that.

```
$("#child").tooltip({
    track: true,
    tooltipClass: "tooltipclass",
    position: { within:"#parent"}
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/6EZHZ/

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks.It worked.It was really helpful.What should i do, to ensure  the toottip to remain at the bottom of pointer.

Comment: Sure thing! I would use `position: { at:"bottom", within:"#parent"}`. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/6EZHZ/2/). However, you can also experiment with `at` by using "center bottom", "left+15 bottom" etc. Here is an [explanation](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) of `at` and `my`.

Comment: There has been delay while using collision:"fit".How can i overcome that.

Comment: What browser are you using? Also are you using any other options? Or just `collison` and `within`?

Comment: I have used track as well as tooltipClass along with collision and within.Like this $("#child").tooltip({
    track: true,
    tooltipClass: "tooltipclass",
    position: { within:"#parent",collision:"fit"}
});

Comment: Did this improve it at all? http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/6EZHZ/3/   if not, I will try a couple other things.

Comment: Nope.The problem was that when 'fit' was used.the pointer moves above the tooltip and thus the tooltip box gets dispersed.I fixed it by using position: { within:"#parent",collision:"fit",my: "left top+15",at: "left bottom"} }); Now the tooltip will lie below the pointer and won't get in way of box

Answer (score 1):

try this

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amYZW/6/)

```
$("#child").tooltip({
   track: true,
   tooltipClass: "tooltipclass",
   position: { my: "left top+15", at: "left bottom", collision: "flipfit" }
});
```